# Undersampling a multi-label DataFrame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sample

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
file_name                                                label

../input/image-classification-screening/train/...         1
../input/image-classification-screening/train/...         7
../input/image-classification-screening/train/...         9
../input/image-classification-screening/train/...         9
../input/image-classification-screening/train/...         6
```

And it has 11 classes (0 to 10) and has high class imbalance. Below is the output of `train['label'].value_counts()`:

```
6     6285
3     4139
9     3933
7     3664
2     2778
5     2433
8     2338
0     2166
4     2052
10    1039
1      922
```

How do I under-sample this data in pandas so that each class will have below 2500 examples? I want to remove data points randomly from majority classes like 6, 3, 9, 7 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a mask that identifies which "label"s have more than 2500 items and then use `groupby`+`sample` (by setting `n=n` to sample the required number of items) on the ones with more than 2500 items and select all of the labels with less than 2500 items. This creates two DataFrames, one sampled to 2500, and the other selected in whole. Then concatenate the two groups using `pd.concat`:

```
n = 2500
msk = df.groupby('label')['label'].transform('size') >= n
df = pd.concat((df[msk].groupby('label').sample(n=n), df[~msk]), ignore_index=True)
```

For example, if you had a DataFrame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': range(30),
                   'label': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                             'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                             'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'F', 'G']})
```

and

```
>>> df['label'].value_counts()

A    13
B    11
C     2
F     2
D     1
G     1
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Then the above code with `n=3`, yields:

```
    ID label
0    7     A
1    0     A
2   10     A
3   20     B
4   18     B
5   21     B
6   24     C
7   25     C
8   26     D
9   27     F
10  28     F
11  29     G
```

with

```
>>> df['label'].value_counts()

A    3
B    3
C    2
F    2
D    1
G    1
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) in a `groupby.apply`. Here s a reproductible example with 4 unbalanced labels.

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':range(100), 
    'label':np.random.choice(range(4), size=100, p=[0.5,0.3,0.18,0.02])})
print(df['label'].value_counts())
# 0    51
# 1    30
# 2    18
# 3     1
# Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Now to select maximum 25 maximum (replace by 2500 for you) per label, you do:

```
nMax = 25 #change to 2500

res = df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=min(nMax, len(x))))

print(res['label'].value_counts())
# 0    25 # see how label 0 and 1 are now 25
# 1    25
# 2    18 # and the smaller groups stay the same
# 3     1
# Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer for larger dataframes where concatenating is expensive to perform.